# Link to 'future' PDF page

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, bookmarks

I am compiling large conference proceedings with many sections in the following way using a kind of Ruby script:

1. I get all articles in PDFs.
2. For each one I calculate page count using `pdftk`.
3. For each section I generate overlaying TeX file with shmutztitle and headings, concatenate articles with `pdftk` and overlay smutztitle and headings with `pdftk`.
4. Then I generate TOC programmatically using `\contentsline` and finally concatenate everything with `pdftk` again. And proudly get single ~30 MiB PDF file as output.

I know all resulting page numbers, but, just as expected, when I try to use `page.4` link in TOC, it just links to page 4 of TOC itself.

Okay, it is always better to have bookmaks in the proceedings, so I started generating them for shmutztitles as `\pdfbookmark[1]{Section Name}{abspage-5}` and for articles as `\pdfbookmark[2]{Article Title}{abspage-7}`. Page numbers are 'global' here, meaning numbers from very final document. Bookmarks work pretty well there and I am happy with them, but...

... But TOC still lags. When I try to reference above article bookmark from TOC with `\hyperlink{abspage-7.2}{7}` (just making page numbers clickable, `.2` is bookmark level as http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~gregory/notes/pdfsl/docs/pdfdoc.pdf prescribes), it points nowhere...

So I tried:

- almost without hope, referencing page numbers;
- with great hope, referencing bookmarks.

And failed both times.

What should I try next, preferably without rewriting the whole system to use one global TeX overlay for the whole proceedings? =)

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to achieve correctly, doesn't the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) packages fit your needs? With that package you can include other PDF documents inside a LaTeX document.

Comment: Yes, [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) was one of possible solutions for me, but as the whole proceedings it very big, I do not want to assemble them with TeX. Concatenating standalone PDFs with `pdftk` is much faster. But they remain _too standalone_ then =)

Comment: You can use `pdfpages` after you've compiled the complete document to include one page at a time and stick labels in that that you create programmatically, something like \foreach \p in [1..P] {\includepdf[pages=\p]{complete} \label{page\p}} .  (Need some fine tuning)